# Ограничение доступа для google forms

Tags: google-forms

Вопрос по поводу гугл форм, если способ ограничить доступ к анкете:
1 раз для 1-го человека?
Пока все что я нашел -- это OAuth2.0, но это не то, что мне нужно.